# Web app no longer opening as standalone (iOS 13)

Tags: iphone-standalone-web-app

Until about iOS11, my simple web app was running fine in standalone mode. In iOS13 it has stopped working as a PWA completely and I can't figure out why. When I add it to the home screen and click on its icon, the web page is opened in iOS Safari, and no longer standalone as a native app. Can anyone see why?

I have tried different advice found on the web, but have found nothing that has helped: Neither removing the apple-specific  tags and relying on the manifest file, nor specifying fullscreen, scope or start_up in the manifest, nor reordering the head tags.

Very grateful for any help!

Here is the relevant  code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="OC bønnebok">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <!-- iphone retina 6 funker med denne -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="oc-applogo-192.png">
        <!-- ipad nonretina ios pre 7 -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="oc-applogo-72.png">
        <!-- iphone non-retina pre ios 7 -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="oc-applogo-57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="oc-applogo-57.png">
        <!-- something android -->
        <link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="oc-applogo-128.png">
...
```

Here is my manifest file, though iOS seems not to care too much (at least it picks the shortcut name from the  tag and not from the manifest:

```
{
    "short_name": "OC Bpnnebok",
    "name": "Bpnnebok for Ordo Crucis",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "oc-applogo-120.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "oc-applogo-152.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "oc-applogo-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],


    "display": "standalone"

}
```